# Installing tfprof command line

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to profile my tensorflow application using [tfprof](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md). I have a running tensorflow 1.3 installation where the the tfprof command line tool is missing. I also tried the provided pip packages locally, but there I also can't find tfprof.

Is there a way to compile and link the tfprof command line tool agains my running tensorflow application?

I already git-cloned the tensorflow repository and tried to build it with bazel 0.5.2

```
$ bazel build --config opt tensorflow/core/profiler/...
WARNING: Output base '/home/USERNAME/.cache/bazel/_bazel_USERNAME/e5cce820cc082410b4fcc604db349066' is on NFS. This may lead to surprising failures and undetermined behavior.
WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: opt
ERROR: /tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1416:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json': target 'gen/spec.json' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.
ERROR: /tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1416:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/head': target 'gen/head' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.
ERROR: /tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1416:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/branch_ref': target 'gen/branch_ref' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /tmp/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/core/profiler:profiler' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 167.083s
```

or just copy the command mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/core/profiler/g3doc/command_line.md)

```
bazel build --config opt third_party/tensorflow/core/profiler/...                                                        
WARNING: Output base '/home/USERNAME/.cache/bazel/_bazel_USERNAME/e5cce820cc082410b4fcc604db349066' is on NFS. This may lead to surprising failures and undetermined behavior.
WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: opt
ERROR: no targets found beneath 'third_party/tensorflow/core/profiler'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the path is not right. You should use path`tensorflow/core/profiler/`, if your current directory is the cloned tensorflow repository.

Answer (score 0):

Run `./configure` script from your tensorflow directory to set the environment variables.